# Cannot connect to Postgres database from RStudio but can connect from DBeaver and psql

Tags: r, rstudio, psql, rpostgresql

Can connect to the database from psql and DBeaver but when using RpostgreSQL package in RSudio I receive the following error:

RPosgreSQL error: could not connect user@hostname on dbname "database": FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "", user "user_name", database "databse", SSL off

Macbook Pro '21, M1, macOS Monterey

Here is my code:

```
tryCatch({
    drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
    print("Connecting to Database…")
    connec <- dbConnect(drv, 
                 dbname = dsn_database,
                 host = dsn_hostname, 
                 port = dsn_port,
                 user = dsn_uid, 
                 password = dsn_pwd)
    print("Database Connected!")
    },
    error=function(cond) {
            print("Unable to connect to Database.")
    })
```

Comment: You probably need to include the `sslmode` argument in the `dbConnect` function. I am not sure what to set it to though. The error reads like the server is configured to only accept SSL connection while client (your R process) is trying to make one without.